# IPv6: Why ping to another IPv6 host doesn't work when loopback interface is DOWN

Tags: shutdown, ipv6, ping, loopback

While it is said the only job of lo interface is to test its own connectivity, why doesn't pinging another IPv6 host work when the lo interface is made DOWN.

**Network configuration:**

- host1(eth0) - 1001::1/64
- host2(eth0) - 1001::2/64

**Steps:**

1. Ping from Host1 to 1001::2; works fine.
2. Make lo interface DOWN on host1.
3. Ping from Host1 to 1001::2; doesn't work.

**Additional Info:**

Debian 3.16.x

```
root@suprman# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

root@suprman# ifconfig lo down

root@suprman# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: Please add the output of `ip a` to your question before and after setting `lo` as down.

Comment: Please add information on which host lo is disabled

Comment: can't reproduce it on linux with 2 connected network namespaces (but of course if lo is down, can't ping one's own ip). maybe 1001::2/64 is on host1 rather than host2 ?

Comment: Hi schaiba, I've added additional information.

Hi mrc02_kr, pinging from Host1 to Host2, lo is shutdown on Host1.

Hi A.B, 1001::2/64 is on Host2.

Comment: Could reproduce with two hosts (Debian 9.5, Kernel 4.9.0) on VirtualBox. Ping Host A to Host B ok. `ip l set down lo` on Host **A** => requests go out, replies comes in(!), but `ping` _doesn't show them._ `ip l set up lo` on Host **A** => working again. `ip l set down lo` on Host **B** => requests still come in, no replies are going out. `ip l set up lo` on Host **B** => working again. But I have no explanation. IPv6 only ping.